# splitting a string in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

i have several strings that look like this:

contactBtn, programBtn, cartBtn.
 How can i split these strings so that the "btn" gets discarted, so i keep contact, program, cart.
How would i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String` class has a `replace` method:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Replace() Section of the ActionScript 3.0 Documentation.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#match%28%29

```
var yourString:String = “contactBtn”
yourString= yourString.split(“Btn”).join(“”);
trace(yourString);
```

// Output : yourString = "contact"

You would just have to iterate through all of your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RegExp :

```
trace(/.+(?=btn$)/gi.exec("foobtn"));//foo
trace(/.+(?=btn$)/gi.exec("fooBTN"));//foo
trace(/.+(?=btn$)/gi.exec("barbtn"));//bar
trace(/.+(?=btn$)/gi.exec("bar"));//null
```